# Blender Python controlling add on

Tags: python, add-on

I'm using an add-on ([latex2blender](https://github.com/ghseeli/latex2blender)).

[image]

If I change one parameter, it will show me in the console how it was done it was done in python. Here I am changing the input to "$ x $":

[image]

Now I know I can use that in python, i.e. writing:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.scene.my_tool.latex_code = "$ x $ "
```

But how can I use python to click the button "Compile as grease Pencil"?

The console just spams custom commands the plguin is using. I was hoping it was possible to do something like "scene.my_tool.button_x_click = True" or something.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add to your imports `import latex2blender` so you can have access to all of the classes of the add-on. After setting the LaTeX code, you can then use `latex2blender.classes[5].execute(latex2blender, bpy.context)` to compile your LaTeX as a grease pencil. Using `classes[4]` would compile as mesh and `classes[3]` would be as a curve.

If you open the latex2blender add-on by right clicking it, going to "show more options", and then "edit with IDLE", you can explore the add-on and see where this all comes from. My file path to the add-on is `C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons` and I had to go to View -> Show -> Hidden items in my file explorer to get AppData to appear.

Her're those classes in the add-on:
[image]

It's unfortunate that these buttons don't appear under `scene.my_tool.`. I think there could be a way to modify the add-on if you really want them to appear there.